# Create custom shape using Bezier Curve in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, bezier

I have one requirement to show the a shape (like  Home or Car etc) and depending upon the percentage of the condition will be filled with animation

[image: See one of the example]

I was trying with image but when I googled, I found this can be achieved by drawing image using Bezier curve.

[image]

So this is the image I am trying to draw and there are other images too.

So here are my two questions :

- Can I achieve this using UIImage directly.
- If not then how can i draw bezier
  curve for such images. How will I calculate the points.

Comment: Refer this link that may help you :https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Comment: Not sure but this will help you : https://github.com/SunnyShah407/DPMeterView

Comment: Sunny Shah : I already referred that code and this also used bezier curve to draw shape

Comment: you can use a series of images and show them accordingly, or you can use bezier path and fill it accordingly! I suggest you using paint code for this one!

Comment: this has nothing to do with Bezier curves - just use a clipping mask where your slide "green" up underneath your mask at the speed of your progress. Done.